# When I use the onSubmit it only executes the actions 1 time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

My problem is that once I execute the function for the first time, which is this input type file, it works perfect, but it remains busy and I cannot use it again, since it does not execute the endpoints

```
          <Uploader
            image="assets/images/icons/product.svg"
            primary="Productos"
            description=""
            onSubmit={this.handleSubmitUploderProducts}
          ></Uploader>
```

When it's done uploading, this calls onSubmit and triggers this. But this only happens the first time, the second time I try to do it, after having uploaded something, for example if I want to replace the file the OnSubmit does not run and it keeps sending the same file, but if I refresh the page if it takes it..

```
  handleSubmitUploderProducts = (event, file) => {
    this.props.openDialog(file, "Product");
  };
```

When this is uploaded it sends open to the modal that I want to show

```
export function openDialog(file, type) {
return (dispatch) => {
dispatch({
  type: OPEN_DIALOG_UPLOAD,
  dialog: {
    file: file,
    type: type,
    open: true
  }
})
}
}
```

And this is the component that does the upload. They all come from different files.

```
const propTypes = {
 onSubmit: PropTypes.func
}
class Uploader extends PureComponent {
constructor(props) {
super(props)
this.state = {
  fileName: false
}
this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
this.fileInput = React.createRef()
}

handleChange(event) {
try {
  this.setState({
    fileName: this.fileInput.current.files[0].name 
  })
  try {
    if (this.props.onSubmit) {
      this.props.onSubmit(event, this.fileInput.current.files[0] ? 
event.target.files[0] : this.fileInput.current.files[0])
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e)
}
}

render() {
const { classes } = this.props
return (<div className={`${classes.root}`}>
  {(this.props.image) ? <div className={classes.iconWrapper}>
    <img className={classes.icon} alt="Icono" src={this.props.image} />
  </div> : null}
  <div className={classes.primary}>{this.props.primary}</div>
  <div className={classes.description}>{this.props.description}</div>
  <div className={classes.inputWrapper}>
    <div className='pointer-events-none flex flex-1 w-full items-center'>
      <Icon className='mt-6 mr-6 mb-6'>cloud_upload</Icon>
      <Typography className='flex-1'>{this.state.fileName || 'Cargar archivo'}. 
  </Typography>
    </div>
    <input className={classes.inputFile} type="file" accept={this.props.accept || 
  '.csv'} onChange={this.handleChange} ref={this.fileInput} />
  </div>
</div>)
 }
 }

Uploader.propTypes = propTypes
Uploader.defaultProps = defaultProps
```

The idea is that every time I upload a new file, execute all the actions as is the due flow, not just once, since I have to leave the view and re-enter, to be able to upload another file

I have been with this problem for more than 6 hours, if someone can help me! Please

Comment: Why use ```ref``` for getting the value when you can get the value from the ```event```? ```event.target.files[0]```

Comment: I can change that, but the problem remains!

Comment: Are you uploading the same file? If then, it won't fire. What you can do is, upon successful dispatch of action, clear the input file value.

Comment: Where? I'm watching and I don't know where

Comment: Something like this? [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-hypatia-lg2nj)